# On Ask Question

Tags: support, bug

When trying to post a question using Ask Question link,

1. The question is not getting posted
2. On typing question, the preview is not being displayed.
3. Rich text editor with options like bold, italic, code sample are not displayed.

And also, drop-downs on header (StackExchange and one related to User).

The console error is:

6 WebSocket connection to 'ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/' failed: Unexpected response code: 502

Comment: What OS and browser are you using? Have you disabled javascript?

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? Do you get any loading errors on the page?

Comment: @Wooble Javascript is enabled. I am using chrome on Windows 7. I have used this facility before but recently it is not working. So I feel it is to do with some browser settings.

Comment: Click F12 and choose Console tab. Do you see errors? If so please add them to your post, either copy&paste or screenshot.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd  The error is 6
WebSocket connection to 'ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/' failed: Unexpected response code: 502

Comment: ...you posted a question about not being able to post a question. Well now you just did! It's working, apparently...

Comment: Weird, but it shouldn't be stopping your from asking questions. No other errors when you suffer the problem you described, assume that oly on the main site?

Comment: Can you post the specific browser version too please? There are sometimes issues with chromes developers channel ([so] doesn't support that chrome version)

Comment: @Lix Chrome version is Version 26.0.1410.43 m

Comment: I'm also seeing something like this, at SO.  Also "Add comment" does not work, and neither does voting. Here at meta it works, as you can see. I suspect it is company firewall.